# Рисование графиков и вставка изображения в текстовое поле (QTextEdit)

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit, qpainter, qpixmap

Как скопировать изображение из *matplotlib...FigureCanvas()*, 
чтобы воспользоваться методом `QTextEdit insertImage()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget

folder    = os.getcwd()

def btnClick(w):
    fnameOld = "screen_shot_{}.png".format(str(w.i))
    if os.path.exists("{}/{}".format(folder, "screen_shot_{}.png".format(str(w.i)))):
        os.remove("screen_shot_{}.png".format(str(w.i))) 
    w.i += 1
    fname = "screen_shot_{}.png".format(str(w.i))

    pixmap = QPixmap(w.plotWidget.size())
    w.plotWidget.render(QPainter(pixmap))
    pixmap.save(fname) 

    w.editor.textCursor().insertImage("{}/{}".format(folder, fname))      # <--------


class MainWindow(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 650)
        self.i = 0

        self.plotWidget = PlotWidget() 
        self.plotWidget.plot(x=[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
                             y=[4.4, 2.5, 2.1, 2.2])

        self.btn = QPushButton("Скопировать изображение графика и вставить в QTextEdit")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: btnClick(self))

        self.editor = QTextEdit()
        self.editor.setAcceptRichText(False)
        self.editor.setAutoFormatting(QTextEdit.AutoAll)
        font = QFont('Times', 12)
        self.editor.setFont(font)
        self.editor.setFontPointSize(12)

        layout = QGridLayout()        
        layout.addWidget(self.editor,      0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.plotWidget,  1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn,         2, 0)         
        layout.setRowMinimumHeight(0, 300)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)   
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Вставка изображений в QTextEdit")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]